# How to use @Startup Annotation for Service that Pushes Data to Websocket?

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, websocket, startup

This is the Java EE7 @Startup annotation for reference. I am using the latest GlassFish server and IntelliJ to run the server.

I need to instantiate this service so that it can send packets of data periodically to a websocket for processing, but the fact that I use

> session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message);

in the end forces me to throw IOException and EncodeException.

This is bad as @Startup or @Singleton disallows usage of Exceptions when instantiating:

> war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [keyBoard_war_exploded] : The lifecycle method [printSchedule] must not throw a checked exception.

Here is my code:

```java
package site.xxxx.models;

import site.xxxx.message.Message;
import site.xxxx.message.TextMessage;
import site.xxxx.modules.Packet;
import site.xxxx.websocket.MainServerEndpoint;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.websocket.EncodeException;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class Service {
    private static Service service;
    Set<Session> peers = MainServerEndpoint.peers;

    @PostConstruct
    public void mainLoop() throws IOException, EncodeException, InterruptedException {
        sendSpamPacket();
    }


    private void sendSpamPacket() throws IOException, EncodeException {
        JsonObject ret = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("type", "textMessage")
                .add("text", "ayyyy")
                .build();

        Packet packet = new Packet(new TextMessage(ret));
        MainServerEndpoint.sendPacket(packet); 
        //results in calling session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Who are you sending data to during startup? The application will not process any requests until the application is successfully started, and this happens after @Startup beans have been initialized. I have not used the EE WebSocket API, but typically you will get an event when the websocket is established, and you need to keep a handle to the websocket session in order to push data to the client.

Comment: Are the exceptions thrown your only blocker?  Can you simply handle them within the method?  Or re-throw them as a RuntimeException

Comment: I need to throw these if I want to use the method mainLoop() after it has been constructed.

Comment: "The application will not process any requests until the application is successfully started, and this happens after @Startup beans have been initialized."     -- this is exactly my problem; I want the application to start and immediately start the mainLoop so that it will start sending packets to the websocket endpoint - even if there are no sessions connected.